# SELECT em VIEW gera sub-consulta?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-select

Gostaria de saber se eu fizer uma `VIEW` com uma consulta simples, se a chamada da view gera um novo SELECT, ou seja, um sub-SELECT totalizando 2 SELECTS ou se apenas aponta para o SELECT de dentro da `VIEW`?

Executei apenas o SELECT de dentro da `VIEW` e executei a `VIEW`, inclusive com algumas variações e pelo plano de execução gerou apenas um `SELECT`.

Gostaria de entender melhor como é feita a execução apenas do `SELECT` em relação a mesma execução através de uma `VIEW`...

O plano de execução otimiza a consulta nesses casos?

Estrutura básica dos testes:

```
CREATE VIEW teste AS
SELECT * FROM Produtos WHERE estoque = 1;
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM Produtos WHERE estoque = 1; 

SELECT * FROM teste

SELECT nome FROM teste

SELECT nome + 'produto' FROM teste
```

---

Quando faço um `SELECT` em uma `VIEW` (que já contém um `SELECT` dentro):

- Apenas um `SELECT` é executado? (Que está dentro da `VIEW`)
- Ou o `SELECT` da `VIEW` mais a consulta interna, gerando dois `SELECTs`?

No meu entendimento o banco de dados faz apenas um link do `SELECT` da `VIEW` direto para o `SELECT` interno da `VIEW`, pois a `VIEW` não é uma tabela, isto está correto?

Atualmente estou usando SQL Server

Comment: Não entendi direito, pode explicar melhor. E diga qual é a base de dados. MySQL?

Comment: Quando faço um SELECT em uma VIEW (que já contém um SELECT dentro), apenas um SELECT é executado? Ou o SELECT da VIEW e a consulta interna, gerando dois SELECTs? Atualmente estou usando SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como consta na documentação BOL a respeito de exibições (*views*) não indexadas, “(...) uma exibição não existe como um conjunto armazenado de valores de dados em um banco de dados. As linhas e colunas dos dados vêm de tabelas referidas em consultas que definem a exibição e são produzidas, *dinamicamente*, quando a exibição é referenciada”.

Quando se cria a exibição, especifica-se o nome e o código da consulta. Para exibições não indexadas o SQL Server armazena então somente metadados da exibição, como a descrição do objeto, colunas, segurança, dependências etc.  Quando se chama uma exibição não indexada, o processador de consultas substitui a referência da exibição por sua definição; ou seja, expande a definição da exibição e após gera o plano de execução.

Como exemplo, temos tabela de produtos.

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE Produto (
  Código int primary key,
  Seção char(1) not null,
  Descrição varchar(80) not null,
  Fornecedor varchar(30) not null
); 
go
```

Podemos criar exibição que retorne somente os produtos da seção de vestuário.

```
-- código #2
CREATE VIEW dbo.Produto_Vestuário 
     with SCHEMABINDING as 
     SELECT Código, Descrição, Fornecedor
       from dbo.Produto
       where Seção = 'V';
go
```

Agora, para listar os produtos da seção de vestuário temos o seguinte código:

```
-- código #3
SELECT Código, Descrição, Fornecedor
  from Produto_Vestuário;
```

Para listar os itens de vestuário de um único fornecedor, temos

```
-- código #4
SELECT Código, Descrição
  from Produto_Vestuário
  where Fornecedor = 'ITA';
```

O que faz o processador de consultas ao analisar o código #4? Inicialmente ele expande o código da exibição no código da chamada:

```
-- código #5
SELECT Código, Descrição
  from (SELECT Código, Descrição, Fornecedor
          from Produto
          where Seção = 'V') as PV
  where Fornecedor = 'ITA';
```

E a seguir entra em ação o otimizador de consultas e a geração do plano de execução.

Para o código #4 ao final é gerado então algo semelhante a

```
-- código #6
SELECT Código, Descrição
  from Produto
  where Seção = 'V'
        and Fornecedor = @1;
```

Isto pode ser confirmado ao analisar o predicado gerado para código #4:

```
#4: [Produto].[Fornecedor]=[@1] AND [Produto].[Seção]='V'
```

**Algumas aplicações**

- mecanismo de segurança para permitir que usuários acessem dados por
  meio da exibição, sem conceder-lhes permissões para acessarem
  diretamente as tabelas base subjacentes da exibição;
- fornecer interface compatível com versões anteriores para emular uma
  tabela que existe, mas cujo esquema foi alterado;
- desenvolver soluções de forma modular. Pode-se resolver cada passo do
  problema com uma consulta, criando então exibição baseada nessa
  consulta. Este processo pode simplificar a solução permitindo focar
  um passo de cada vez.

**Referências**

- [Exibições](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/views/views)
- Ben-Gan, Itzik. Chapter 1 - Views. In:[T-SQL Programming](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/inside-t-sql-2008-programming/).

Comment: Excelente explicação, muito obrigado José!

Comment: Manda demais em SQL. 